# Getting an Image from URL in Python: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f890a076db0>

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I have a list of thousands of urls that I need to use to grab images.

The urls are stored in a list, and iterate over each url running the below code. The example is shown for a specific url:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import urllib

ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

URL = 'https://www.sedie.ws/dynamic/common/data/d/files/45000/45217_2_3-med.jpg'

label = 'table'

r = requests.get(url = URL)

filepath = "{}.jpeg".format(label)

try:
    response = requests.get(URL)
    data = response.raw.read()
    data = BytesIO(data)
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))      
    im.thumbnail((64, 64))
    im.save(filepath) 
    count += 1

except IOError as e:
    print(e, URL, '\n')
```

However this returns an error:

```
cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f890a076db0> https://www.sedie.ws/dynamic/common/data/d/files/45000/45217_2_3-med.jpg
```

Could someone please explain how to handle this image correctly? I would like to simply skip this file and not have to download it, but I find that my try catch is still saving some files to my local system. However, upon trying to read them I get the above errors too.

Comment: The provided url is not a jpg resource, but a dynamic web page, do you tried this code on other sites with static jpgs?

Comment: Hi, the issue is I just have a really long list of urls and cannot check whether the url works correctly or not. Is there a way to handle this programmatically?

Comment: The url isn't an image so that's why it fails, if you want to catch "not-image urls" use except PIL.UnidentifiedImageError ( https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open )

Comment: Ah thank you -  I am new to this that is very helpful